# How to use if else between two orderBy in eloquent laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to use if else between two orderBy in eloquent laravel

```
->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
->join('hr_applicants', 'hr_applications.hr_applicant_id', '=', 'hr_applicants.id')
->orderBy('hr_applicants.name', 'ASC')
```

Comment: what kinda condition you have to apply to your query?

Comment: I want to apply two sortby name and date if I click name then it sortby name if I click date then it sortby date.

Comment: pass your column name in the parameters on the click function, and use it within the query.
->orderBy($columnName, Asc);

Comment: I want use if else condition between two orderBy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure how you're doing things, but you could probably do something like this:

```php
$query = .... /*your query code here*/
  ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
  ->join('hr_applicants', 'hr_applications.hr_applicant_id', '=', 'hr_applicants.id')
  ->orderBy('hr_applicants.name', 'ASC');

if ($condition1) {
  $query = $query->orderBy('table.column', 'ASC');
} else {
  $query = $query->orderBy('table.column2', 'DESC');
}

$result = $query->get();
```

Comment: I have two table one table name is hr_applicants and another is hr_applications. If I select name then sortby only name and I select Date then only sortby date.